# Регулярные выражения: предложения с двузначными числами

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки

Пытаюсь подобрать регулярное выражение для предложений с двузначными числами (если в числе 3 и более знаков, оно не подходит). Пытался использовать

`[^0-9]*[0-9][0-9][^0-9]*`

но оно возвращает true при фразе "У меня 100 рублей"
я использую c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для C#:

```
(?<!\d|\.)\d\d(?!\d|\.)
```

Не заработает, например, в JS, так как там нет просмотра назад. А так будет работать и с числами вначале, и с числами в конце, пропустит дробные числа (на всякий случай).

Answer (score 1):

Звёздочки мешают. Проверял на [сайтике](https://www.myregextester.com/index.php) Выражение: `[^0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]`

Строка: `Не имей 100 друзей, а имей 30 подруг по 14 раз в неделю`

Результат:

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  30 
            [1] =>  14 
        )

)
```

Comment: Igor N. Еще неплохо было бы добавить проверку на случай, если число найдено в начале или конце входных данных.

Comment: Да, если число в начале или конце предложения-не подходит |$ не помогает

Comment: `@"(^|\D)\d\d(\D|$)"` - усовершенствованный вариант регулярки; работает и в начале, и в конце предложений.